# Same ID multiple states

Tags: sql, ssms

I am pulling in ID #s. For each ID# there is a state 'Approved', 'Exists', 'Draft', 'Active', 'Review', 'Preliminary', 'Development', or NULL OR obsolete.
I **don't** want to include any rows where ID equals Obsolete.

Sometimes there will be more than 1 ID # and sometimes there will only be 1. I am trying to state if the ID # is the only 1, then just pull it in.
However if there is more than one ID #, I want to check if one of the states equal 'Release'.
If it does and the other state equals NULL, then I only want the 'Release' state.

However, I don't want to prevent NULL values from pulling in altogether because there may be an instance where there is only one ID and that is the state (NULL).
In this case, I would to pull in to the results.

I was thinking I need to have a CASE WHEN clause in my WHERE statement where if ID HAVING COUNT > 1, then check the states.

If this were my data:

```
53689875  state = Obsolete  SID # 1
78569852  state = NULL SID # 2
72215538  state = NULL SID # 3
72215538  state = Release SID # 4
78542155  state = Approved SID # 5
75369521  state = Draft SID # 6
32586846  state = Release SID # 7
32586846  state = NULL SID # 8
44855221  state = Obsolete SID # 9
65475331  state = Development SID # 10
56665875  state = NULL SID # 11
21233698  state = Release SID # 12
11558254  state = Review SID # 13
11558254  state = Obsolete SID # 14
89756852  state = Obsolete SID # 15
```

This would be my output expected:

```
78569852  state = NULL SID # 2
72215538  state = Release SID # 4
78542155  state = Approved SID # 5
75369521  state = Draft SID # 6
32586846  state = Release SID # 7
65475331  state = Development SID # 10
56665875  state = NULL SID # 11
21233698  state = Release SID # 12
11558254  state = Review SID # 13
```

Comment: When an ID has more than one state, could you have occasions where the combination is different than what you listed in your sample data? Like DEV and DRAFT? If so, would you want to display both?

Comment: If the only combinations when more than one state is present include those combinations from your sample data, then the easiest way is `select id, max(state) as state from t1 where state <> 'Obsolete' or state is null group by id`. But if you could have other combinations, then a longer solution is needed.

Comment: @Isolated this is what I actually had originally.  But for some reason it was not working.  I have other tables joined to this base table.  and there are other conditions called out in the where clause.

If I have the table by itself it does actually seem to work.  But with the other tables.  It is not working.  Which has me a little dumbfounded bc the state exists only in this main table..  And the other tables are left or inner joins.  Nothing that is keeping data from the other table first.

Comment: I think I see why now... I have another identifier in my table.  I am grouping by that SID # first which is essentially voiding the group by on the ID as the primary.

Comment: So I have what may seem like a silly question...  we HAVE to include all the columns we are including in the SELECT in our GROUP BY... so how do I get around this?  I tried just reordering the main ID before the SID # and that didn't work. I need the SID # to be included.  With the SID included, it basically wants to pull both rows in with a NULL and Release state instead of only the Release.

Comment: I would probably recommend updating your question with more accurate sample data. Doesn't have to be everything, but enough to meet the various concerns you have. I suspect you'll need a CTE or sub-query to get what you need.

Comment: Okay, will provide a sample SID #.  It is a unique identifier for that row of data.

Comment: Updated.. so this works without the SID in the group by - but as soon as I add the sid it does not work:
without sid:
select id, max(state) as state from t1 where state <> 'Obsolete' or state is null group by id
with sid:
select sid, id, max(state) as state from t1 where state <> 'Obsolete' or state is null group by id, sid

Comment: This appears to work... am I approaching this accurately? 

select subtable.ID, max(subtable.state), max(subtable.SID)
from  mytable a
inner join 
 (select SID, ID, state
 from mytable subtable
 group by subtable.name, subtable.SID, subtable.state) subtable on a.SID = subtable.SID
where subtable.ID = '72215538' 
and (subtable.state <> 'Obsolete' or subtable.state is null) 
group by subtable.ID


given the sample data above this would return : 
72215538  state = Release SID # 4

Comment: @Isolated - have a question on your previous question above...When an ID has more than one state, could you have occasions where the combination is different than what you listed in your sample data? Like DEV and DRAFT? If so, would you want to display both? – 
Isolated
 20 hours ago ...

I am not 1000% sure. I tried finding an instance where this was true.  But I am not certain it wouldn't be true in the future.  IF... it were true... there was a released state and a development state.. would the below with the CTE show both???  And if not, is there a way for it to show both?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First cut based on modified data. I cannot think of a way to avoid a self-join or subquery, but this should work.

```
create table t1 ( 
  id integer, 
  state varchar(20), 
  sid integer
  );
```

```
insert into t1 values 
(53689875, 'Obsolete', 1),
(78569852, NULL, 2),
(72215538, NULL, 3),
(72215538, 'Release', 4),
(78542155, 'Approved', 5),
(75369521, 'Draft', 6),
(32586846, 'Release', 7),
(32586846, NULL, 8),
(44855221, 'Obsolete', 9),
(65475331, 'Development', 10),
(56665875, NULL, 11),
(21233698, 'Release', 12),
(11558254, 'Review', 13),
(11558254, 'Obsolete', 14),
(89756852, 'Obsolete', 15);
```

```
with cte as (
 select 
  id, 
  max(state) as state
 from t1
 where state <> 'Obsolete' or state is null
 group by id
)
select t.id, t.state, t.sid
from t1 t
join cte c
  on t.id = c.id
 and (t.state = c.state or c.state is null)
order by 3
```

| id | state | sid |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 78569852 | *null* | 2 |
| 72215538 | Release | 4 |
| 78542155 | Approved | 5 |
| 75369521 | Draft | 6 |
| 32586846 | Release | 7 |
| 65475331 | Development | 10 |
| 56665875 | *null* | 11 |
| 21233698 | Release | 12 |
| 11558254 | Review | 13 |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/Wcy3OqRq)

Comment: This appears to work!  What are you referencing as "3" in your "Order by 3"?

Comment: That's the 3rd column in the select statement. Same as saying `order by t.sid`

Comment: If this answers your question, then please consider marking the Accept flag.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this could be food for thought

```
select * 
  from (
    select *,
           rank() over ( 
               partition by id
                   order by case when state is null then 0
                                 else 1
                             end desc
           ) state_precedence
      from your_table
     where coalesce(state,'') <> 'obsolete'
) t
where state_precedence = 1
```

So if there's only one id with null state, that will have the max rank and be selected. But if there's more than one record for that id, you'll exclude the nulls.

This is just a general approach I tend to use when doing this kind of precedence select. You'll probably have to tweak it depending on the exact behavior you want - if you have two (or any number) records for the id and they are all null, this will bring in all of them. Don't know if that's what you want.

Also, if you have multiple records 1 "obsolete", 1 "null" this will bring in the null.

Comment: For some reason this is excluding the individual ones that have NULL states...?

Comment: @user22441973 Ah, derp. My bad. I'd added the filter for <> obsolete as an after thought and didn't handle nulls. The coalesce sorts that out.